# Spring Security using filter and not Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

Trying to setup login authentication with Spring Boot starter 2.3.0 and Spring Security 5.3.2

My `loginController` was working initially a `/login` POST request

Then I added Spring Security and a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, and other classes to authenticate that I copied from other apps and it works.

It's going out and authenticating the username and password but it doesn't go through the `Controller` `/login` method. It seems to just skip it (sysout logs aren't showing). But if I remove the method then it doesn't work (so it's like it has to be there but doesn't go into it).

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
   http
    .csrf().disable()
    .cors()
    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(SecurityConstant.PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .addFilterBefore(
    //      authenticationFilter(),
            jwtAuthorizationFilter,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?  Thanks, appreciate any help, trying to learn Spring Security

Comment: Spring Security handles the login you don't need the controller. Also, you added a JWT filter while you mention username/password. Finally, you haven't enabled form login on your security config.

Comment: I have two filters, RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter which takes in the username/password(in the RequestBody) from an Angular app...and now I'm trying to add a JWT token, so I've included the JwtAuthorizationFilter

Comment: My tutorial was showing how they generate the token in the controller, but if I don't go to the controller because of my setup, then the filter authenticates and in my AuthenticationSuccessHandler is where I can generate that token, before returning to my Angular login page.

Comment: I can get that to work and you answered my question that I don't need that Controller method, thanks.